# Concatenate two files content into a single file

Tags: batch-file

I have collected some data in a text file file1.txt from Process Explorer using wmic as follow:

```
wmic process where Caption='NOTEPAD.exe' get ProcessId,VirtualSize /Format:Texttable > file1.txt
```

### file1.txt:

```
ProcessId  VirtualSize  
5752       74649600     
3932       76843610
1357       90215638
```

in another text file file2.txt, i have following data:

### file2.txt:

```
Notepad.exe.exe pid: 5752 windows
Notepad.exe.exe pid: 3932 linux
Notepad.exe.exe pid: 1357 macos
```

Now as ,process ids are matching in both the files so can i generate a consolidated single output file (Matching the processId in both the files) having following content using batch script:

### Output.txt:

```
windows  74649600  
linux    76843610
macos    90215638
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with plain text files, but Wmic is a weird beast sometimes.
It adds extra carriage returns in the output sometimes.

```
@echo off
(for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%a in (file1.txt) do (
for /f "tokens=5" %%c in ('find " %%a " ^< file2.txt ') do echo %%c %%b
))>file3.txt
```

Comment: Hi Fox..great this works superbly.!!.:)...my only concern now is; Is there any limitation for no. of .bat files in a specific folder..? because when i put this batch file with four other .bat files(one of four is wmic.bat ) in a single  folder..this script is surprisingly not working .

Comment: A problem we all strike at times is when calling a batch file name the same name as an executable.  If you have `wmic.bat` and it launches `wmic` inside it then it will launch itself, and fail to run correctly.  That is possibly what is happening for you - or another batch calls wmic and the wmic.bat file is launched instead.

Comment: In path C:\BATCH i have 3 files
'file1.txt
file2.txt
my.bat having above code'

but now its not producing any output

Comment: Pls see EDIT1 in question.

Comment: I am shocked..! this time it worked..!..how this is happening..? how many maximum no. of .txt and .bat files i can put in a single folder which are calling each other..? is it the cause of my issue..?

Comment: Hi Fox..above script is running on windows 7 but not on windows 2008 server..i have five .bat files to run one by one..first four .bat are running but this one is not running..at the same time its running sepeartely on windows 7..any suggestion..?

Comment: when i put file1.txt and file2.txt along with my.bat in a empty folder ..then its working..but when fil1.txt and file2.txt are being created in a folder where my.bat resides respectively from Pid.bat (using wmic)and App.bat files..then its not working..:(

Comment: join me in the chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38611/batch-files and tell me the exact filenames of all the files - we'll see if there is an issue there.

Comment: Hi Fox..got the resolution..!! :):)..just did insert a copy command to copy content of Pid.bat's output file to another static file..& after that Its working on server 2008 like a charm..!! i noticed your first comment line: 
**Wmic is a weird beast sometimes.
It adds extra carriage returns in the output sometimes.**..:):)..Thanks a lot..!!